# ASP.NET MVC 3 - Unit Test in Respository

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I'm using a class test that checks login entity that is being done correctly, but an error occurs that does not seem to return the query in the database, but the application developed in ASP.NET MVC 3 Code First query returns data, I would to know what is wrong and what can be done to solve it.

Upon return of the query gives the following message in the variable:
***"Enumeration yielded no results"***

Test Method:

```
[TestMethod()]
public void efetuarLoginTest()
{
            EntidadeRepository target = new EntidadeRepository();
            string cnpj = "12345678";
            string senha = "lalado";
            Entidade expected = null; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
            Entidade actual;
            actual = target.efetuarLogin(cnpj, senha);
            Assert.AreNotEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

Method repository of the entity with the task of returning to the login query:

```
public Entidade efetuarLogin(string cnpj, string senha)
        {

            var consulta = from usu in bd.Entidades
                           where usu.cnpj == cnpj && usu.senha == senha
                           select usu;

            if (consulta.Count() > 0)
            {
                Entidade e = new Entidade();
                e.id_entidade = consulta.First().id_entidade;
                e.razao_social = consulta.First().razao_social;
                e.cnpj = consulta.First().cnpj;
                e.senha = consulta.First().senha;

                return e;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Class persistence database using the Entity Framework 4.1:

```
internal class BancoDados: DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions.PluralizingEntitySetNameConvention>();
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions.PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

        public DbSet<Entidade> Entidades { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Estado> Estados { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Administrador> Administradores { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Leilao> Leiloes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Lance> Lances { get; set; }
    }
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for us, this kind of an error was generated because of the right connection string not passed to the EF. If you are using NUnit, NUnit doesn't use your app.config or web.config, you would have to create your assembly.dll.config or nunit project.config. Please check NUnit documentation for usage of config files.

You can verify the connection string passed to NUnit, by examining, DbContext.Database and its properties in debug mode/

Checking your config values, should fix your problem.

Comment: I added m XML file called app.config in visual studio test runs successfully but need to run in NUnit renaming the project name in. dll to. dll.config which is located in the directory bin / Debug has a step by step because it's not working. Thank you.

Comment: check out http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=configFiles&r=2.2.10, follow these steps, this should help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine

```
if (consulta.Count() > 0)
```

is throwing the error?

You could change it to

```
if (consulta != null && consulta.Count() > 0)
```

Comment: But even with this change the query returns null because these test data exist in the database, but the problem persists in the connection with the database.